# Counting Cells containing especific Values

Tags: excel, vba

Hi im new using excel and i would like to count the cell that containg the values betweeen 500 and 750. this is the code that i wrote but i did something wrong that is not giving me the right answer. Can some one please help?

```
Sub Count()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Range("C3").Select

    For i = 1 To 279
        For j = 1 To 19
            If i > 500 Then
            ElseIf i <= 750 Then
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = i
End Sub
```

Comment: Which range do you want to check? Your code does not check any cell value. Also, this _might_ be able to achieve by `=COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 3):

Why use VBA for that?

Use [`COUNTIFS()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) function. Just enter it in cell `B13` and adjust the range from `A:A` to whatever range you need to check in the formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, ">=500", A:A, "<=750")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code with few tweaks works.

```
Sub count()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim countCell As Integer

    Range("C3").Select

    For i = 1 To 279
        For j = 1 To 19
            If Cells(i, j).Value >= 500 And Cells(i, j).Value <= 750 Then
                countCell = countCell + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox countCell & " Cells Found", vbInformation

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B13").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = i
End Sub
```